# using CAS with with custom login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas

I've implemented jasig-CAS in my application, but now I'd like to know more.
Is it possible to do my own login page and then it would automatically(in background) authenticate the user in CAS.
so the steps are next:

1. user goes to the login page
2. user enters his credentials
3. if authentication succeeded, user's credentials are sent to CAS, thus CAS authenticates user in its system and gives a ticket(user shouldn't see any CAS pages)
4. user accesses protected pages

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the REST API.  [CAS REST](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API)

I use this for in-login i.e. Drupal.  Since you are not redirecting the user doesn't see any CAS pages.

So that steps would be:

1. User goes to the login page.
2. User enters crendetials.
3. Your application posts the username and password to CAS via REST.
4. Your application, upon successful authentication, gets a Ticket Granting Ticket back.

At this point you can log him in to your application ( he's already logged in to CAS ) or validate the ticket you received THEN log him in.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need get a copy of CAS official client source code( cas-client-core ), and make sure you could compile it.
2. You need change the doFilter() function code at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter in client source code like the below.

   ```
   final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
   final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
   final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   final Assertion assertion = session != null ? (Assertion) session.getAttribute(CONST_CAS_ASSERTION) : null;

   if(request.getServletPath().toLowerCase().equals("/caslogout.jsp"))
   {
       // Set the custom client login page when you logout from CAS server.
       request.setAttribute("casServerLogoutUrl",casServerLoginUrl.replace("login","logout"));
       request.setAttribute("customServerLoginUrl",customServerLoginUrl);

       //We must remove the attribute of CONST_CAS_ASSERTION manually
       if(session!=null)
           session.removeAttribute(CONST_CAS_ASSERTION);

       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       return;
   }

   if (assertion != null) {
       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       return;
   }

   // Although the custom login page must called caslogin, here you can change it.
   if(request.getServletPath().toLowerCase().equals("/caslogin.jsp"))
   {
       //Set the a default parameter to the caslogin
       request.setAttribute("defaultServerIndexUrl",defaultServerIndexUrl);
       request.setAttribute("casServerLoginUrl",casServerLoginUrl);
       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       return;
   }

   final String serviceUrl = constructServiceUrl(request, response);
   final String ticket = CommonUtils.safeGetParameter(request,getArtifactParameterName());
   final boolean wasGatewayed = this.gatewayStorage.hasGatewayedAlready(request, serviceUrl);

   if (CommonUtils.isNotBlank(ticket) || wasGatewayed) {
       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       return;
   }

   final String modifiedServiceUrl;

   log.debug("no ticket and no assertion found");
   if (this.gateway) {
       log.debug("setting gateway attribute in session");
       modifiedServiceUrl = this.gatewayStorage.storeGatewayInformation(request, serviceUrl);
   } else {
       modifiedServiceUrl = serviceUrl;
   }

   if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
       log.debug("Constructed service url: " + modifiedServiceUrl);
   }

   final String urlToRedirectTo = CommonUtils.constructRedirectUrl(this.casServerLoginUrl, getServiceParameterName(), modifiedServiceUrl, this.renew, this.gateway);

   if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
       log.debug("redirecting to \"" + urlToRedirectTo + "\"");
   }

   // Add a custom server login url parameter to the CAS login url.
   response.sendRedirect(urlToRedirectTo+"&customLogin=custom&customLoginPage="+customServerLoginUrl);
   ```
3. Add your own compiled cas-client-core to the dependence of your client webapp.
4. Add the caslogin.jsp to your client webapp.

```html
     <form method="GET" action="<%=request.getAttribute("casServerLoginUrl")%>">
    <p>Username : <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
    <p>Password : <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="auto" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="service" value="<%=request.getParameter("service")==null?request.getAttribute("defaultServerIndexUrl"):request.getParameter("service")%>" />
```

5. Edit the web.xml in client webapp. Add below code in the filter of CASFilter

```html
<init-param>
    <param-name>defaultServerIndexUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>http://clientip:port/webappname/index.jsp</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>customServerLoginUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>http://clientip:port/webappname/caslogin.jsp</param-value>
</init-param>
```

6. Edit the code at cas-server-webapp/WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/casLoginView.jsp in CAS server web app.

```html
<%
  String auto=request.getParameter("auto");
  String customLogin=request.getParameter("customLogin");

  if(auto!=null&&auto.equals("true"))
  {
    %>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script language="javascript">
        function doAutoLogin()
        {
          document.forms[0].submit();
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="doAutoLogin()">
    <form id="credentials" method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/login?service=<%=request.getParameter("service")%>">
      <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="${loginTicket}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
      <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%=request.getParameter("username")%>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="login_form" value="<%=request.getParameter("login_form")%>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="true" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="visibility: hidden" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <%
}
else if(customLogin!=null&&customLogin.equals("custom"))
{  
  response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("customLoginPage")+"?service="+request.getParameter("service"));
%>
<%
}
else
{%>
<!-- The Orgin Source Code of casLoginView.jsp!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
<%}%>
```

7. Now you could login cas with your own caslogin.jsp!

I also make a sample about how to login cas with client custom login screen rather than  server login srceen. You could download it on 

https://github.com/yangminxing/cas-custom-login-page

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need SSO, then yes you can, as rexposadas said, using CAS REST. 
Here is a good java example in how to implement: http://www.bmchild.com/2014/05/a-simple-cas-java-rest-client-example.html

But that won't work with SSO, in other words, you won't be able to login in appA and then auto-login in appB. That's because the cas login page creates a TGT cookie that is used for SSO. By REST, you don't get that cookie created.

But again, if you don't need SSO, then CAS REST will do.

Answer (score 0):

The updated CAS documentation has a page on **User Interface Customization**:

https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/User-Interface-Customization.html

Note that the CAS site and documentation have moved since the original post and some other answers.

CAS Home - https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/index.html

CAS on Github - https://github.com/apereo/cas

Legacy CAS Wiki - https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home

Comment: The CAS Home link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Using external forms to enter credentials is not recommended and widens the attack surface. See https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/planning/Security-Guide.html

If one breaches your external Form application, attackers got access to all SSO connected systems.